# Predict on continuous variable for Logistic Regression model in which feature was trained as a binary variable?

Tags: logistic, binary-data, categorical-encoding

Let's say I have a binary logistic regression model trained on several binary categorical variables (i.e. the model is only trained on 0s and 1s for these variables). For example, Feature A can only be 1 (yes) or 0 (no).

Now, when I use the model for prediction, let's say I know that in a particular case for Feature A there is a 70% chance that it is "yes" and a 30% chance that it is "no".

Can I then have the model predict on 0.7 for Feature A?

I *think* this works given that LogReg doesn't actually know the difference between continuous and binary variables. It would just apply 70% of the coefficient associated with that feature. In theory it would be the same as taking the weighted 70/30 average of the output predictions.

Comment: You wrote:

 let's say I know that in a particular case for Feature A there is a 70% chance that it is "yes" and a 30% chance that it is "no".

Do you mean that the data is missing for that case?

Comment: Looks like a case for using the law of total probability.

Comment: @PeterFlom yes, but based on other datasets we know something about the probability of yes vs no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the same as taking the weighted 70/30 average of the output predictions, because logistic regression uses a nonlinear transform of $X'\hat{\beta}$ to form its predictions.

Let us assume we have one independent predictor $X$ that takes on values in $\{0,1\}$.  Let's further assume the coefficient estimate equals $1$.  We then have:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
p(y=1 | x=1) = {e^{1} \over 1+e^1} = 0.731...\\
p(y = 1 | x = 0) = {1 \over 1+e^1} = 0.269...\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

The 70/30 weighted average of these two numbers is 0.5924.  This would, as Frank Harrell suggested in a comment to the OP, be the correct calculation.

But
$$ p(y = 1 | x = 0.7) = 0.668...$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand now why using 0.7 as the predictor for feature A is not the same as the weighted 70/30 average of the output predictions. However, is there some transformation I can apply to 0.7 so that the transformed value would produce the same result as the 70/30 average? My apologies if the answer is already in your reply and I'm missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  You'd need a different number for every combination of the regressors, which you'd only be able to calculate by calculating the "correct" weighted average number and then reverse-engineering, so to speak, what the transformation of 0.7 would be from that.   But you'd already know the correct number, so there's no point in figuring out the transformation.  Really, though, the extra calculation should be very, very fast, especially since it's on predictions rather than requiring a run of the estimation routine.